# SVN User Oddity from PHP exec()

Tags: php, apache, svn

I am running PHP code that invokes a script through exec(). This script runs an `svn commit` command with no user specified. The user (let's call him NICK) that runs this script (verified by a call to `whoami`) has a certificate under `~/.subversion` which is specified in `~/.subversion/servers` with the `ssl-client-cert-file` option. This certificate file has a username attached to it (seen by outputting the certificate's content [like so](http://bsdsupport.org/2008/12/how-do-i-determine-the-expiration-date-of-a-p12-certificate/)).

**When this script is invoked via a cron job on NICK's crontab, the SVN author of the commit is the same as the one in the certificate I mentioned earlier. But when the same script is invoked via PHP's exec() function, the author of the commit is a different user.** I can't for the life of me figure out why this other user is being used. I've tried giving the commit command the `--username` option, and I've also tried using `svn propset svn:author` to no avail. Does anyone know why this could be the case? Is PHP / Apache using a different certificate? Any information on what is going on or how to alter this behavior would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried prefixing your command in exec with sudo?

```
exec('sudo -u nick ./path/to/script');
```

Comment: Just did and the user is still different than from the cron job.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand correctly, are you initiating the PHP script via php cli, or are you making a wget or curl request to through Apache, Nginx, etc to trigger the script?

Comment: Can you add the line in your crontab as well?

Comment: The PHP script is being run through Apache. Do you mean you'd like to see the line in the crontab or if I can add a line to my crontab? The crontab line is something I'm trying to get rid of; rather than this commit happening on a timer I'm trying to have it be triggered by a call to a certain PHP function.

Comment: I meant add the crontab line to your question.

Comment: It's something like /home/NICK/script.sh, nothing complicated going on. The exec() call is simply exec("/home/NICK/script.sh")

Answer (score 0):

Apache is usually configured to run as nobody. If you are invoking the script from the browser. It will run as the user apache is configured with.

Comment: The Apache user is the same as the one who owns the crontab. :(

Comment: What about php? Are you running it as fastcgi? That could run as a different user.